# Firestore security rules - How to only allow certain fields in a map inside a map

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a document named "list" which contains a field named "list" which is a map of where the values are a new map that should only contain the keys "color" and "description". I am trying to write rules that makes sure the keys are only "color" and "description", but I can't seem to find a way to restrict the key names in a map inside a map.

[image: example]

(the reason its a map of maps inside a singel document is because i have a security rule where a field of type array only can contain elements specified from "list.list.keys()")

I have tried

```
request.resource.data.list.values()[request.resource.data.list.values().size()-1].keys().hasOnly(["color", "description"])
&& request.resource.data.list.values()[request.resource.data.list.values().size()-1].keys().hasAll(["color", "description"]);
```

but that doesn't work as the index of the new value is random as its a map.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you know all the possible names of the keys of values under `list` ("Dependencies" and "Testing" in your case able), this will not be possible to enforce.  There is no way of wildcarding map keys, and there is currently no way of iterating map keys.  You must know the full paths of everything that could be added in order to check them with security rules.